# Importing and processing a text file

Tags: r, text

I have a text file (`myfile.txt`) which looks as follows,

Subject: `5581 2005 471791 80 15184 64 2155 5581 2005 80 21292 10607 47 64 209 22910 132 1672 84 3865 84 1570 84 2005 84 10492 1847 12330 4797 82 13886 2170 47`

What I want is a vector `A` such that its elements will be as follows

`A[1]=5581  A[2]=2005  A[3]=471791` .....  and so on

I tried `read.table()` and `readLines()` which didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `scan` to read the file to create a `vector` of class `numeric`

```
A <- scan("myfile.txt", what = numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
```

If there is also the `Subject:` as prefix in the beginning, we read the file with `readLines`, remove the prefix part with `sub`, and read it with `scan`

```
lines <- readLines("myfile.txt")
A <- scan(text= paste(sub("^\\S+\\s+", "", lines), collapse=" "),
                      what = numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
```

Regarding the regex (`^\\S+\\s+`), we are matching one or more non white-space characters (`\\S+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by one or more white space characters (`\\s+`) and replace it with blanks (`""`) in the `sub`.